# How to hide button when in-app purchase is compelted

Tags: ios, iphone, objective-c, in-app-purchase

I have a ViewController where the user makes the purchase for their in-app product. They press a button to make the purchase, however once the purchase is complete, I want the button to hide and I want to show `thankyou.text = @"Thanks for purchasing";`

**Here's the code in my viewcontroller:**

```
#import "SponsorViewController.h"
#import "NJKWebViewProgressView.h"


#import "RageIAPHelper.h"
#import <StoreKit/StoreKit.h>


@interface SponsorViewController ()

{
    NSMutableArray *_objects;

    NSArray *_products;

    NSNumberFormatter * _priceFormatter;


}

@end

@implementation SponsorViewController

- (NSString *)publisherIdForAdSdkBannerView:(AdSdkBannerView *)banner {
    return @"e0616d4190bff65279ed5c20de1b5653";
}

- (id)initWithNibName:(NSString *)nibNameOrNil bundle:(NSBundle *)nibBundleOrNil
{
    self = [super initWithNibName:nibNameOrNil bundle:nibBundleOrNil];
    if (self) {
        // Custom initialization
    }
    return self;
}

- (void)awakeFromNib
{
    [super awakeFromNib];
}

- (void)viewDidLoad
{

    [super viewDidLoad];

    [RageIAPHelper sharedInstance];

    _products = nil;

    [[RageIAPHelper sharedInstance] requestProductsWithCompletionHandler:^(BOOL success, NSArray *products) {
        if (success) {
            _products = products;

        }
    }];



    // Price New



    SKProduct * product = (SKProduct *) [_products objectAtIndex:0];


    ([[RageIAPHelper sharedInstance] productPurchased:product.productIdentifier]);


    // Unlock your features code comes here

    UIButton *buyButton = [[UIButton alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(-1, 310, 320, 60)];
    UIImage *btnImage = [UIImage imageNamed:@"upgrade-new.png"];
    [buyButton setImage:btnImage forState:UIControlStateNormal];
    [buyButton.titleLabel setFont:[UIFont boldSystemFontOfSize:13.0]];
    [buyButton setTitleColor:[UIColor whiteColor] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
    [buyButton.titleLabel setShadowColor:[UIColor colorWithWhite:0.1 alpha:1.0]];
    [buyButton.titleLabel setShadowOffset:CGSizeMake(0, -1)];
    [buyButton addTarget:self action:@selector(buyButtonTapped:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
    buyButton.tag = 0;
    [[self view] addSubview:buyButton];



    UIButton *restoreBtn = [[UIButton alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(-1, 370, 320, 60)];
    UIImage *restoreImg = [UIImage imageNamed:@"restore.png"];
    [restoreBtn setImage:restoreImg forState:UIControlStateNormal];
    [restoreBtn.titleLabel setFont:[UIFont boldSystemFontOfSize:13.0]];
    [restoreBtn setTitleColor:[UIColor whiteColor] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
    [restoreBtn.titleLabel setShadowColor:[UIColor colorWithWhite:0.1 alpha:1.0]];
    [restoreBtn.titleLabel setShadowOffset:CGSizeMake(0, -1)];
    [restoreBtn addTarget:self action:@selector(restoreAction:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
    restoreBtn.tag = 0;
    [[self view] addSubview:restoreBtn];




    // Purchase Action End


    [super viewDidLoad];


    _priceFormatter = [[NSNumberFormatter alloc] init];
    [_priceFormatter setFormatterBehavior:NSNumberFormatterBehavior10_4];
    [_priceFormatter setNumberStyle:NSNumberFormatterCurrencyStyle];
    [_priceFormatter setLocale:product.priceLocale];




    self.view.layer.shadowOpacity = 0.75f;
    self.view.layer.shadowRadius = 10.0f;
    self.view.layer.shadowColor = [UIColor blackColor].CGColor;



}

- (IBAction)dismissView:(id)sender {

     [self dismissViewControllerAnimated:YES completion:NULL];

}




- (UIStatusBarStyle)preferredStatusBarStyle
{
    return UIStatusBarStyleLightContent;
}



- (void)buyButtonTapped:(id)sender {

    UIButton *buyButton = (UIButton *)sender;
    SKProduct *product = [_products objectAtIndex:buyButton.tag];

    //    NSLog(@"Buying %@...", product.productIdentifier);
    [[RageIAPHelper sharedInstance] buyProduct:product];

}



- (IBAction)restoreAction:(id)sender
{
    [[RageIAPHelper sharedInstance] restoreCompletedTransactions];

}
```

Would appreciate any help with this :)

Answer (score 1):

The Singleton you're using to do the IAP (RageIAPHelper) comes from this tutorial:

**Introduction to In-App Purchases in iOS 6 Tutorial**
by Ray Wenderlich
http://www.raywenderlich.com/21081/introduction-to-in-app-purchases-in-ios-6-tutorial

I would suggest you read thru that article for details on how exactly to use it.

If you dig thru the source, you'll see this snippet in the IAPHelper.m class:

```
- (void)buyProduct:(SKProduct *)product {

    NSLog(@"Buying %@...", product.productIdentifier);

    SKPayment * payment = [SKPayment paymentWithProduct:product];
    [[SKPaymentQueue defaultQueue] addPayment:payment];

}

- (void)paymentQueue:(SKPaymentQueue *)queue updatedTransactions:(NSArray *)transactions
{
    for (SKPaymentTransaction * transaction in transactions) {
        switch (transaction.transactionState)
        {
            case SKPaymentTransactionStatePurchased:
                [self completeTransaction:transaction];
                break;
            case SKPaymentTransactionStateFailed:
                [self failedTransaction:transaction];
                break;
            case SKPaymentTransactionStateRestored:
                [self restoreTransaction:transaction];
            default:
                break;
        }
    };
}
```

The `buyProduct` method initiates the purchase, and the `paymentQueue:updatedTransactions` method is called when the App Store responds.  Knowing those two things, you can respond accordingly.  For example, you might subclass `IAPHelper`, implement your own `paymentQueue:updatedTransaction` method and have it do what you wish.

Answer (score 0):

You are creating a property for your button to the interface (so you can reach it from you whole class):

```
@property (nonatomic, strong) UIButton * buyButton;
```

then:

```
self.buyButton = [[UIButton alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(-1, 310, 320, 60)];
```

and when the transaction is completed (I assume you have a function somewhere what handles the transaction states):

```
_buyButton.hidden = YES;
```

Answer (score 0):

This is how I do it in my apps. you can change this code purchaseMyAppSuccessful and do whatever you need to after the purchase is successful

```
- (void)paymentQueue:(SKPaymentQueue *)queue updatedTransactions:(NSArray *)transactions
{

    for (SKPaymentTransaction   *transaction in transactions)
    {
        switch (transaction.transactionState) {
            case SKPaymentTransactionStatePurchasing:
                NSLog(@"About to purchase ...");

                break;

            case SKPaymentTransactionStatePurchased:
                NSLog(@"Item is successfully purchased ...");

                [self purchaseMyAppSuccessful];
                [[SKPaymentQueue defaultQueue] finishTransaction:transaction];
                break;

            case SKPaymentTransactionStateRestored: 
                NSLog(@"Payment Restored ...");

                [self purchaseMyAppRestored];
                [[SKPaymentQueue defaultQueue] finishTransaction:transaction];
                break;

            case SKPaymentTransactionStateFailed:
                NSLog(@"Payment Failed ...");

                if(transaction.error.code != SKErrorPaymentCancelled)
                {
                    NSLog(@"An error occured ...");
                    [self purchaseMyAppFailed];
                }
                else
                {
                    NSLog(@"Payment was cancelled ...");
                }

                [[SKPaymentQueue defaultQueue] finishTransaction:transaction];
                break;

            default:
                break;
        }

    }

}

- (IBAction) purchaseMyAppSuccessful
{
    [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] setObject:@"1" forKey:@"MyAppWasPurchasedStr"];
    [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] synchronize];

        //Alert Show
    UIAlertView *alert = [[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:@"Success" 
                                                        message:@"You have successfully unlocked this app. Have fun!"
                                                       delegate:self cancelButtonTitle:@"Ok" 
                                              otherButtonTitles:nil];
    [alert show];





}
```